# Publish 2 version of same application using webpack module federation

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

We are using module federation for create a web application. We are facing issues to load different version of same application.

We are using promise dynamic remotes to load different version of same application.
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#promise-based-dynamic-remotes

Below is our current webpack configuration for main app

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;
const ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin = require('external-remotes-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const packageJsonDeps = require('./package.json').dependencies;
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index',
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 3001,
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: 'auto',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'app1',
      remotes: {
        app2: 'app2@[app2Url]/remoteEntry.js',
        app3: 'app3@[app3Url]/remoteEntry.js',
      },
      shared: {
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: packageJsonDeps['react'],
        },
        'react-dom': {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: packageJsonDeps['react'],
        },
      },
    }),
    new ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```

In this case app2Url , app3Url are pointing to different version of same application.

Below is the webpack configuration for provider app.

```js
 const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;
const path = require('path');
const packageJsonDeps = require('./package.json').dependencies;

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index',
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 3003,
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: 'auto',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // To learn more about the usage of this plugin, please visit https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-federation-plugin/
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'app2',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './App': './src/App',
      },
      shared: {
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: packageJsonDeps['react'],
        },
        'react-dom': {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: packageJsonDeps['react'],
        },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```

Use case : - We are doing experimental role out of features and due to that we want to publish 2 different version of remote entry and using our experimental tool we will enable the features for few users.

We are getting below error while loading different version of same application

Loading script failed.
(missing: http://localhost:3003/remoteEntry.js)
while loading "./App" from webpack/container/reference/app3
ScriptExternalLoadError: Loading script failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you launch the second application with the name app2 and the remoteEntry for the version of app2 you will only expose the application with the name app2 with its remoteEntry.

If you also need an app3 to be able to expose or reach it, you need to launch an application that has a configuration with app3 in the ModuleFederationPlugin.

A possible solution would be to do the two builds separately and then add something like this in the plugins:

```
plugins: [
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: 'app2',
  filename: '[app2Url]/remoteEntry.js',
  exposes: {
    './App': './src/App',
  },
  shared: {
    react: {
      singleton: true,
      eager: true,
      requiredVersion: packageJsonDeps['react'],
    },
    'react-dom': {
      singleton: true,
      eager: true,
      requiredVersion: packageJsonDeps['react'],
    },
  },
}),
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: 'app3',
  filename: '[app3Url]/remoteEntry.js',
  exposes: {
    './App': './src/App',
  },
  shared: {
    react: {
      singleton: true,
      eager: true,
      requiredVersion: packageJsonDeps['react'],
    },
    'react-dom': {
      singleton: true,
      eager: true,
      requiredVersion: packageJsonDeps['react'],
    },
  },
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './public/index.html',
}),
]
```

This would allow you to have both remoteEntrys available, but there are several considerations to make:

- Are the changes seen for the two different versions, or is it still getting only the main version?
- This code works for the project run, for the build you have to do them individually for each version of app2 and app3.

Let me know if you have solved it or if this can be useful to you, by adapting the code in your own way.

Comment: We are exposing 2 remote entry files from provider app and adding that to consumer app and with feature flag we are able to control that.